# For which values of $\alpha, \beta, x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 0$, does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^ \alpha x^{n^{\beta}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to study, for $\alpha, \beta, x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \geq 0$, the convergence/divergence/irregularity (i.e., when the limit of the $N$-th partial sum does not exist) of the following series:

> > $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^ \alpha x^{n^{\beta}}.$$

Until now, I've only done similar exercises, but only with one parameter.

Could you show me how this kind of problem with more than one parameter should be done (paying also attention to notation and rigour), so that I have some guidance? In fact, unfortunately, in my exercise book there are no worked examples at all.

Comment: Are you trying to decide for which $x \ge 0$ this series converges?

Comment: @zhw. I've edited the question to add some clarity.

Comment: Might as well assume $x>0$. The case of $x=0$ is trivially convergent

Comment: **Hint:** What happens when *a* and/or *b* are positive and/or negative ? And what happens when *x* is greater or lesser than $1$ ?

Comment: @Lucian Could you show me the details (since, as I've said, this is the first exercise of this kind that I've ever done)?